# Submit listing then login/register

Tags: forms, registration, workflow, process

I need users to submit a listing but they need to be registered. I want to make it easier by allowing them to fill in the submit form.

I am thinking of 3 approaches:

1. Once the listing is validated the next screen should be either login or register.
2. On the submit listing form I include an email field and check if it's a registered email if it is then ask for password, if not generate a password and get the new email registered (implicitly getting them to register).
3. User fills in the listing form, then chooses register/login based on input new fields are added - only caveat is that for new users, 4 new fields are added (username, email, password and password confirm) and also further validations.

Are these intuitive? What is the better approach or are their other better ways?

Comment: It looks like you've found that registration is a barrier to submitting listings. Moving the barrier to the end of the process is unlikely to solve the problem - in fact you're likely to end up with more users who actively dislike your system because they feel that you've tricked them into registering. However, if you add value for registered users (some insight, features, etc) that is not available to unregistered users then you will find that more users are likely to register and you can then ask them to submit a listing.

Answer (score 1):

The main question here is if you want the user to think about

1) Signing up to yet another service.

2) Adding the content for the listing.

Usually users are more concerned with the service a site or a product offers, and the opportunities it brings them. Not so much about the fact, that they need to leave some data, sign up etc.

With this in mind, you flow seems natural and intuitive. And my hunch is that the experience will be more about easy and exiting to get started, than about feeling trapped in the end, having to go through a simple sign up step. You need to be sure though, that no users will feel offended by the terms they have to accept at that point.

Comment: I require the user to be registed because of the model it is being built on, do you think letting the user register first before the can submit is a good idea, or leave the login/register till the end?

Comment: To me, this depends on the nature of your service. If you regard the listing to be added as something exciting to the user, any annoyance about subsequent practicalities of creating an account is no problem. In many cases the user understands that this is necessary to be able to store the data. 
It you but the sign up/registration before the listing creation, you run the risk   of the user not caring to start the process, and you can loose any momentum based on the user's excitement.